# EFI/Bios/Grub: Notebook Doesn‘t boot neither HDD nor Fedora install media

Tags: linux, boot, bios, grub, efi

I had a parallel installation of W10 and Fedora Linux. Was fine although prompting error of unknown TPM error the last time but the Notebook booted.

Then I Installed Fedora 39 immutable Onyx. Deleted both previous installation.  Went good but same error.

After a couple of rebooting it doesn’t boot anymore.
Neither my installation nor a newly prepared installation media with Fedora 39.

Error message:
Could not create NokListTrustedRT: Out of Resources
Something has gone seriously wrong: import mok_state() failed: out of Resources

Then power off

When I disable secure boot Grub is loading but only with troubleshooting.
And then:
error:../../grub-core/commands/efi/tpm.c:150 unknown TPM error
Press any key to continue

Also set EFI settings to default.
Approx 10 year old American Megantrend.

Anybody a hint what I can do here? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Restore from last drive image. 2. If no image was made, recover data then remove all partitions and reinstall *ab initio*.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231992/failed-to-set-moklistrt-out-of-resources-import-mok-state